# How to Update Multiple Document With _id in mongodb with PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

i have used Mongodb with PHP

MongoConnection

```
class mongoManager{
    private $db;
    private $collection;
private function mongoConnect($collName){
        $con = new Mongo(URI);
        //$this->databaseName = $dbname;
        $this->db = $con->dbname;

        $this->collection = $this->db->$collName;

        return $con;
    }
 public function mongoUpdate($collName, $idFind, $updateValues){
    if($this->mongoConnect($collName)){
        if($this->collection->update($idFind, $updateValues)){
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

}
```

i have php array which is containing ids, i Want to Update Documents with following array of ids.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => 58ec62e5ae8715a410000003
        [1] => 58ec6227ae8715a410000002
    )
```

i have updated single document with php following script, but i struggle with Multiple document update

singleDocUpdate.php

```
<?php
    $mongoObj = new mongoManager();
    $et_id = array('_id'=>new MongoId($_GET['id']));
    $updateValues = array(
                "\$set"=> array(
                        "stat"          => "A",
                        "approved_by"   => $_SESSION['id'],
                        "approved_date" => $today
                )
            ) ;
    $res = $mongoObj->mongoUpdate('AllEvents', $evnt_id, $updateValues);
?>
```

Comment: Why do you struggle? Do you see any error? What is not working? Please elaborate on your problem. Also Example #3 on http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.update.php#refsect1-mongocollection.update-examples is talking about updating multiple documents

Comment: no i struggle with query formation because single document update i have mentioned single id, but muliple document updates  how to mentioned multiple id in same query?

Comment: You're looking for $in operator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/